# Can I statically prevent one function from calling another?

Tags: c++

I have the following interfaces:

```
class T {
public:
    // Called in parallel
    virtual unsigned validate () = 0;

    // Called with a lock taken out
    virtual unsigned update () = 0;
};

template <typename DataType>
class Cache {
public:
    // Gets the requested object.
    // If it doesn't exist in memory, go to SQL.
    unsigned fetch (DataType &data);


    // Gets the requested object.
    // If it's not in memory, returns NOT_FOUND.
    unsigned find (DataType &data);
};
```

**What I'd like to achieve:** I would like to be able to have compilation fail if `fetch` is called during `update`. Effectively, I'd like to disable the function statically, based on the call site. Something like,

```
std::enable_if <callsite_is_not_implementation_of_T_update, unsigned> 
fetch (DataType &data);
```

Usage would work something like this:

```
class A_T : public T {
public:
    virtual unsigned validate () {
        global_cache.fetch (object); // OK
    }

    virtual unsigned update () {
        global_cache.find (object); // Also OK

        global_cache.fetch (object); // FAIL!
    }
};
```

---

#### Background

There are approximately 500 implementations of `T` in my project.

The application loops in many threads and calls `validate` for many instances of `T` in parallel. Then a global lock is taken out, and `update` is called. Hence, the speed of `update` is crucial. The general attitude is to take whatever time you need during `validate`, but `update` should be as lean as possible.

**My problem** is with the use of`Cache`. A `Cache` is basically an in-memory cache of data objects from SQL.

The policy is to never call `Cache::fetch` during `update` because of the potential SQL round-trip while holding a lock. We're all working hard to foster this mindset within the team. Unfortunately, some of these still sneak in, and get past code review. We only notice them when the system is under heavy load and everything grinds to a halt.

I'd like to develop a safety net and prevent this kind of  thing from being allowed at all. What I'd like to achieve is to have compilation fail if `Cache::fetch` is called from `T::update`.

I don't mind if it can be worked around. The point is to have it as a barrier; the only way you could make a mistake is to intentionally do it.

---

#### What I've Got So Far

I've made it a little bit of the way there, although not quite what I'm really after. For instance, I'd prefer not to have to change every single call to `fetch`.

```
template <typename Impl>
class cache_key  {
    cache_key() { }
    friend unsigned Impl::validate();
};

#define CACHE_KEY cache_key<std::remove_pointer<decltype(this)>::type> ()
```

So now `Cache::fetch` looks like:

```
unsigned fetch (DataType &object, const cache_key &key);
```

And an implementation of `T` might look like this:

```
class A_T : public T {
public:
    virtual unsigned validate () {
        global_cache.fetch (object, CACHE_KEY); // OK
    }

    virtual unsigned update () {
        global_cache.fetch (object, CACHE_KEY); // Can't do it!
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `std::mutex`?

Comment: @JustinWood In what way?

Comment: If it's possible to split the interface T in two, then ordinary C++ access protection and `friend` will do the trick. Oh and that might also simplify things by separating the free-threaded and single-threaded code.

Comment: Another idea is that of "key and lock", that the caller must have something (e.g. instance of some specific type) to pass as otherwise dummy argument. Just the possession is important. Then make sure that only valid call sites have that thingy. Might be easier to arrange static checking of.

Comment: Third idea: institute a well-known policy that anyone who makes the stupid "forbidden" call, has to stand on one foot and emit loud cackling noises interspersed with the phrase "i'm caaaaaaaaaaaaaaling you" for 15 minutes in a very public place, where it will be filmed.

Comment: To give the key to `validate` I'd have to pass it as a parameter. If I can do this without having to change any implementations of `T`, that would be great. I'm currently trying to wrap my head around your multiple inheritance suggestion.

Comment: compile time?  No.  Run time?  yes.  Have it do nothing, log, crash, throw, assert, format c: if you do it?  sure.

Comment: would you also want to handle the case that update() calls a function in another CU, which calls fetch() ?

Comment: @tristan Yes, if possible; although it's not such a prevalent problem.

Comment: @anthony-arnold maybe you can use some tools to generate a static call graph and find the path from update to fetch.

Comment: This seems hacky, so it is just a comment.  What if you require to pass in the global_cache to each method that would use it.  Then you can have a base class Cache and have a derived version, methods being virtual.  Your global cache would be an implementation of the derived, but you would pass it as the base to the update() methods.  You can make fetch a template method with specializations which takes itself as a parameter. Have the base class specialization cause a compile error.

Comment: You can allow a fixed set of functions and classes to call you , disallowing all others. That's what friend declarations are for. You cannot disallow a fixed set while allowing all others.

Comment: Yes, but friendship isn't inheritable. It would be good to be able to do this without listing all implementations of `T::validate` .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of compilation time error generation, but it can be done to generate run-time error with updates only to base class.

A way to do it is to call update through a non-virtual proxy function in a base class, which would set state to the base class to detect that we are in update and therefore fetch should not be called.

```
class updateWatcher()
{
public:
updateWatcher(bool *valIn) : val(valIn) {*val=true;}
~updateWatcher() {*val=false;}
private:
bool* val;
}

class T {
public:
    // Called in parallel
    virtual unsigned validate () = 0;

    unsigned updateProxy()
    {
         updateWatcher(&inUpdate); //exception safe tracker we are in update
         return update();
    }

    void
protected:
    // Called with a lock taken out
    virtual unsigned update () = 0;

    bool inUpdate; // tells if we are in update or not
};

class A_T : public T {

public:
    virtual unsigned validate () {
        global_cache.fetch (object,inUpdate); // OK
    }

    virtual unsigned update () {
        global_cache.find (object); // Also OK

        global_cache.fetch (object,inUpdate); // FAIL (put assert in global_cache.fetch) !
    }
};
```

This will not produce compilation but run-time error, benefit is that there is no need to update any implementations (except replacing all global_cache.fetch (...); by global_cache.fetch (...,inUpdate); and calls to update() to updateProxy(); in all implementations, which can be automated efficiently). 
You can then integrate some automated tests as part of the build environment to catch the asserts.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a stupid POC, which I don't recommend, and may not fulfill your expectations:

```
struct T {
    // Called in parallel
    virtual unsigned validate () = 0;

    // Called with a lock taken out
    virtual unsigned update () = 0;
};

struct A_T : T {
    unsigned validate () override;
    unsigned update () override;
};

template <typename DataType>
class Cache {
private:
    class Privileged {
        friend class Cache<DataType>;

        friend unsigned A_T::validate();

        Privileged( Cache<DataType> &outer ) : outer(outer) {}

        // Gets the requested object.
        // If it doesn't exist in memory, go to SQL.
        unsigned fetch (DataType &data);

        Cache<DataType> &outer;
    };

public:
    Privileged privileged { *this };

    // Gets the requested object.
    // If it's not in memory, returns NOT_FOUND.
    unsigned find (DataType &data);
};

Cache<int> global_cache;

unsigned A_T::validate () {
    int object;
    global_cache.privileged.fetch (object); // OK
    return 1;
}

unsigned A_T::update () {
    int object;

    global_cache.find (object); // Also OK
    global_cache.privileged.fetch (object); // FAIL!

    return 1;
}
```